# C# PowerPoint создать фотоальбом

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Всем привет, кто нибудь знает как в powerpoint создать фото альбом программно на C# ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что уже пробовали?

Comment: Что пробовали? но эту задачу я решил.